# How to solve the electromagnetic field around a rectangular dielectric waveguide analytically?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, dipole, waveguide

If I have an electric dipole placed outside of a rectangular dielectric waveguide, how can I solve the boundary condition problem to find the reflected and transmitted fields due to the presence of the waveguide?

It is well-known that one can find separate variables of the electromagnetic field/mode for a rectangular conductor waveguide, but I haven't found a way to apply similar separation of variables strategy to solve the fields around a dielectric waveguide with the same shape. There are approximated methods to ignore the field components at the corners of the waveguide. Is there any better way to just find the total reflected field outside of a rectangular/square waveguide? Thanks!

Comment: Not every boundary value problem has an analytical solution.

Comment: This is a very difficult analytical problem and it cannot be solved by separation of variables. The subject of dielectric rod antennas (these are really waveguides of rectangular or circular cross section) as well as the modes they propagate in particular  have a vast literature. I suggest that you look into the IEEE Transactions on Antennas and Propagation under the heading "dielectric rod antennas".

Comment: Thanks. I know the eigenmodes cannot be solved using the separation of variables method due to the index of refraction, but I wonder if I only care about the reflected fields from a dipole, would the problem become easier? Will dig into the literature for more insight.

Comment: The is something called the Geometric Theory of Diffraction that treats the diffraction from corners and edges in a generalization of geometric optics. Perhaps that can be helpful.